# Deleting rows for which a column value appears fewer than a given number of times conditional on uniqueness

Tags: r, row

I have data that looks like

```
date player market 
1-1     1     1
1-1     2     1
1-1     1     2
1-2     2     1
1-2     3     2
1-2    12     3
1-2    11     3
1-2     2     3
1-3    24     3
1-3     4     4
1-3    21     1
1-4     1     1
1-4    51     1
1-4     1     1
1-5     1     2
```

I want to delete all rows related to the column Market that have appear in fewer than in three unique dates.

So this would delete all rows except for those in which the Market column is 1 or 2.  This is a simplified version of what I am doing, so looping is out of the question.

Is there a quick way to do this?

There are 60,000 markets.

Comment: `subset` for market < 3?

Comment: I changed the data so this will not work (this would leave out market 3), since it ignored the unique dates issue. Is it possible to use subset with some logical command that conditions on market >3, counting a market only if the markets are in different dates?

Comment: I think I misunderstood earlier. Just to confirm - the market column is some sort of ID and you want to check whether the same market ID occurs across multiple dates, and then if it occurs more than thrice then you want to filter it. Right?

Comment: Yes, correct, if it occurs on more than three unique dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df` is your data.frame to begin with -

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,Freq := length(unique(date)), by = market]
dt2 <- dt[Freq > 2]
```

Output -

```
> dt2
    date player market Freq
 1:  1-1      1      1    4
 2:  1-1      2      1    4
 3:  1-1      1      2    3
 4:  1-2      2      1    4
 5:  1-2      3      2    3
 6:  1-3     21      1    4
 7:  1-4      1      1    4
 8:  1-4     51      1    4
 9:  1-4      1      1    4
10:  1-5      1      2    3
```